# two pandas columns have identical values written differently

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame where multiple columns contains the same data, stored differently.

For example, a column is full of Carrier Names (AA for American Airlines, etc), and another column is full of Carrier IDs.

How can I quickly check whether these two columns are actually filled with the same information (that each Carrier indeed has only one ID ?) the goal being to safely drop one of the two columns ?

So far, I've got the following :

```
#for each carrier
for carrier in data.CARRIER.unique():
    #print all the different AIRLINE_ID that appear when we subset the data for this carrier
    print(carrier, data[ data['CARRIER'] == carrier].AIRLINE_ID.unique())
```

This gives me back the list of each unique ID for each carrier, and since every CARRIER only has one value for ID, I can safely drop one of the columns.

I just wanted to know whether there was a pandas function that does this without looping and checking. (Because I've read somewhere that anytime you start writing code to manipulate a DF, a function probably exists somewhere ^^)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby`, `nunique`, and `all`:

```
(df.groupby('ID')['CARRIER'].nunique().eq(1)).all()
```

This will return `True` if there is only one `CARRIER` per `ID`, and `False` otherwise.

**For example:**

When you have one `CARRIER` per `ID`

```
>>> df
   ID  CARRIER
0   1   AA
1   2   BB
2   3   CC
3   1   AA
4   2   BB

>>> (df.groupby('ID')['CARRIER'].nunique().eq(1)).all()
True
```

But on the other hand, when there are multiple different names per `ID` (Here, `ID` 2 has 2 different `CARRIER`):

```
>>> df
   ID   CARRIER
0   1   AA
1   2   BB
2   3   CC
3   1   AA
4   2   DD

>>> (df.groupby('ID')['CARRIER'].nunique().eq(1)).all()
False
```

You can also see which `ID` has multiple `CARRIER` values using:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')['CARRIER'].nunique()
ID
1    1
2    2
3    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

This shows you that `ID` 2 has 2 unique `CARRIER` values

Comment: Hello, that was quick and spot on ! thank you very much !

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Comment: it does, I knew of the existence of groupby, but never had an instance of where it could be applied (I guess I didn't know we could use it that way). And I knew about .unique(), but not .nunique(), so I was always doing len(data.unique())... so I learned two things today, not too bad ^^